# How to avoid concurrent read access issue in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am getting a date value from a `tblinfo` table. If the date is null, then I will insert into table, else I will update the row in the table.

I am facing the issue that 2 sessions accessing the table simultaneously with same information, both are getting `Null`, so both are trying to insert records into same table with same primary key value. We are getting the primary key constraints issue. How to stop this?

```
begin tran
     set @date=(select date from tblinfo where id=@id)
        if(@date is null) 
        --insert 
    else 
    --update 
commit tran
```

Comment: Can you what you're really trying to do? You could avoid this altogether by using `IDENTITY` or `SEQUENCE`, as your primary key, then update that row afterwards with a date.

Comment: primary key is not an identity . We are getting information from another application .Such like if there is any insert or update or delete ,we will get those information \

Answer (score 4):

**Using Locking**

```
declare @Date DateTime
, @RowId bigint = 10

Begin Tran
select @Date = SomeDate 
from tblInfo 
with (RowLock) --this is the important point; during the transaction, this row will be locked, so other statements won't be able to read it
where Id = @RowId

if (@Date is Null)
begin
    insert SomeTable (TblInfoId, Date) 
    values (@RowId, GetUtcDate())
end
else
begin
    update SomeTable 
    set Date = @Date 
    where tblInfoId = @RowId
end
if @@TranCount > 0 Commit Tran
```

**Technique Avoiding Locking**

If preventing reads from occurring is an issue for some reason, the below is a lockless approach; but requires an extra field in your database.

```
declare @Date DateTime
, @RowId bigint = 10
, @DataAvailable bit

Begin Tran

update tblInfo
set session_lock = @@SPID
where Id = @RowId
and session_lock is null

select @Date = SomeDate 
, @DataAvailable = 1
from tblInfo 
where Id = @RowId
and session_lock = @@SPID

if (@DataAvailable = 1)
begin
    if (@Date is Null)
    begin
        insert SomeTable (TblInfoId, Date) 
        values (@RowId, GetUtcDate())
    end
    else
    begin
        update SomeTable 
        set Date = @Date 
        where tblInfoId = @RowId
    end
    update tblInfo
    set session_lock = null
    where Id = @RowId
    and session_lock = @@SPID
end
--optionally do something if the row was already "locked"
--else
--begin
    --...
--end
if @@TranCount > 0 Commit Tran
```

Comment: Inserting `NULL` for `Date` is probably not ideal. You might want to at least add a comment to the code suggesting that a suitable value be provided for the `INSERT` case.

Comment: Good point; amended to use `GetUtcDate()` there; though obviously what the logic does is up to the op; it's the locking mechanism that's important in answering the question.

Comment: shall i proceed with first option ?

Comment: Probably.. I don't know your requirements / full scenario, but I suspect option 1 would be best.

Comment: In first (`ROWLOCK`) example, if there is no row with the specified `Id` then no lock will be taken. Doesn't that present a synchronization issue for multiple simultaneous sessions?

Comment: @JohnLBevan, the first method (using locking) doesn't work. selecting the tblInfo will not lock any row, if there is no record for the select.

Comment: if there is no row for that record , then how to handle this scenarios

Comment: I`d assumed that date is nullable, rather than simply date being null only if no match exists. Could easily add code to handle the scenario where no match exists, or where the date column`s not nullable. Let me know your requirements and I can tweak.

Answer (score 1):

Right after "begin tran", update your table like below script

```
begin tran 

-- this update will lock the table so no other process can read data
update tblInfo with (tablock)
set date = date


---- do what ever you need to do here
set @date=(select * from tblinfo)

if(@date is null) 
    --insert 
else 
    --update 

commit tran
```

this will cause SQL Server lock the table and the second transaction will wait reading the data until the first process finish.

Comment: basically we are checking whether  the record is available or not .begin tran
     set @date=(select * from tblinfo where id=@id)
        if(@date is null) 
        --insert 
    else 
    --update 
commit tran

Comment: OK, before select run the update. the table will lock and second process will wait. isn't that what you need? see my edit

Comment: if the record is not there ,then we have to insert .if already same id is there, we have to update

Comment: I edited my answer. even if your table is empty, the first update statement, locks your table and no other process can select from table. any other select will wait until you commit or rollback transaction.

Comment: update tblInfo with (tablock)...i could not get it ... what it will do ? Update tblinfo set name=@name where id=@id.. same meaning ?

Comment: if there is no record ,update will fail .. that is why we are checking whether the record is there or not

Answer (score 0):

Relying on lock hints to get the desired outcome will perhaps prevent you from attempting to insert the value twice, but it won't prevent errors from happening.  You'll just get an 'Unable to acquire lock' or deadlock error instead.

You should put a mutex in your code, in the minimally sized critical section.  Using sp_getApplock, you can get a lock on a section of code with a wait period that you specify (subsequent threads will wait for the lock to clear and then continue).  Here's some sample code:

```
declare @LockResource nvarchar(100) = 'VALUE_INSERT'    
begin transaction

    -- Fetch the lock:
    EXEC @res = sp_getapplock                 
                    @Resource = @LockResource,
                    @LockMode = 'Exclusive',
                    @LockOwner = 'Transaction',
                    @LockTimeout = 10000,
                    @DbPrincipal = 'public'

    if @res not in (0, 1)
    begin
        set @msg = 'Unable to acquire Lock for ' + @LockResource
        raiserror (@msg , 16, 1)
        rollback transaction
        return
    end 
    else
    begin
        begin try
            ---------------------------------------------
            -- Fetch value if it exists, insert if not.
            -- Both need to happen here.
            ---------------------------------------------
        end try
        begin catch
            select @msg = 'An error occurred:  ' + ERROR_MESSAGE()

            -- Release the lock.
            EXEC @res = sp_releaseapplock 
                    @Resource = @LockResource,
                    @DbPrincipal = 'public',
                    @LockOwner = 'Transaction' 

            rollback transaction
            raiserror(@msg, 11, 1)
            goto cleanup
        end catch

        -- Release the lock.
        EXEC @res = sp_releaseapplock 
                @Resource = @LockResource,
                @DbPrincipal = 'public',
                @LockOwner = 'Transaction' 
    end

    commit transaction
```